# Material UI grid with IntputLabel and Input placed in horizontal row: how to ask vertical-align to be middle for the label?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vertical-alignment

I have pretty standard React Material UI grid with InputLabel's and Input's placed in horizontal row. The code is:

```
const Container = (props) => <Grid container {...props} />;
const Item = (props) => <Grid item xs={1} {...props} />;
const ContainerItem = (props) => <Grid container item {...props} />;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={ucs_theme}>
        <Container>
          <ContainerItem>
            <Item>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="m_gen_ref_serie">Serie</InputLabel>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input type="text" id="m_gen_ref_serie" />
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="m_gen_ref_serie2">Serie 2</InputLabel>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input type="text" id="m_gen_ref_serie2" />
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="m_gen_ref_serie3">Serie 3</InputLabel>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input type="text" id="m_gen_ref_serie3" />
            </Item>
          </ContainerItem>
          <ContainerItem>
            <Item>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="m_gen_ref_serie">Serie</InputLabel>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input type="text" id="m_gen_ref_serie" />
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="m_gen_ref_serie2">Serie 2</InputLabel>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input type="text" id="m_gen_ref_serie2" />
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="m_gen_ref_serie3">Serie 3</InputLabel>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input type="text" id="m_gen_ref_serie3" />
            </Item>
          </ContainerItem>
        </Container>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And full example is available:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-material-ui-example-forked-f0ir9?file=/src/index.js

Be aware, that my codesandbox example uses some theming, but the problem is not affected (not solved) by this theming (at least by this kind of theming).

I have problems and my question is about the placement of the InputLabel (rendered as HTML label) text - it is placed left-top. The left-placement is OK. **The problem is that I don't like that the text is placed as top (some console entries who some strange margin-bottom). I would like to set `vertical-align="middle"` for this text. But there is not such property for InputLabel. How can achieve `vertical-align="middle"` effect for my labels (text of the labeld) in the Material UI grid?**

Maybe I have to use some strange intermediate components like Paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your items alignment by using the props `alignItems`

`<Grid container justify='center|flexStart|flexEnd|...' alignItems='center|end|start|....' alignContent='center|....' ...props >`

Just look at the documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/) for more informations, you can also use CSS rules on your `Grid item` to edit the placement